# limit a random number generator to only output 20 of 50 numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need some help or advice I am trying to limit the random number to only generate 20 out of the 50 numbers and this activated when a button is pressed/clicked sometimes i get duplicates too which i would to stop happening

```
function lottoNumbers()
    {
      var lottoNums = [];
      for(var i=0; i <1 ; i++)
      {
        var temp = Math.floor(Math.random() *50);
        if(lottoNums.indexOf(temp) == -1)
        {
          lottoNums.push(temp);
          document.getElementById('circle'+i).innerHTML = lottoNums[i];
        }
        else
        {
          i--;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: So, to clarify, is the function supposed to output a random 20 numbers less than 50 with no duplicates?

Comment: Plenty of dupes.... generate the numbers, random sort, pick from the array....

Comment: yes it is Obsidian, then i have searched online with logic and using shuffle an array

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a for loop - use a **while** loop (ie - while length < 20) and as you are doing - only push the numbers into it if they are not already there.

For demo purposes- i am building a list dynamically and then styling the li's to give a rounded shape with border-radius;

```js
lottoNumbers();


function lottoNumbers() {
  var lottoNums = [];
  var lottoNumStr = '';
  
  while(lottoNums.length <20) {
    var temp = Math.floor(Math.random() *50);
    if(lottoNums.indexOf(temp) == -1) {
      lottoNums.push(temp);
      lottoNumStr += '<li>' + temp + '</li>';
    }
  }
  
  document.getElementById('lottoNumList').innerHTML = lottoNumStr;
}
```

```css
#lottoNumList {
  list-style: none;
}

#lottoNumList li {
 border: solid 1px #d4d4d4;
 border-radius: 50%;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 5px;
 padding: 4px;
 width: 30px; 
 height: 30px;
 line-height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Lotto Numbers</h1>
<ul id ="lottoNumList"></ul>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the advice, tho i tried but could not get it to work as in mine after a button is clicked it generates my random number one at a time